# PHP Calculate starttime and end time from a list of mintues with ID's

Tags: php, sql, datetime, loops

Sorry to bother again. I have searched tried my best, looked everywhere and still cannot solve the problem. Could you please help? - I would try my best to explain the problem.

Problem:
I have a list of times with an ID and I want to loop through those time within an ID to get the start times and end times. This is an example:

```
   time_id           time_duration

 1   2010-10-15 11:15:00
 1   2010-10-15 11:20:00
 1   2010-10-15 11:25:00
 1   2010-10-15 11:30:00
 2   2010-10-15 11:35:00
 2   2010-10-15 11:40:00
 2   2010-10-15 11:45:00
 2   2010-10-15 11:50:00
 2   2010-10-15 11:55:00
 3   2010-10-15 12:00:00
 3   2010-10-15 12:05:00
 4   2010-10-15 12:10:00
 5   2010-10-15 12:15:00
 5   2010-10-15 12:20:00
 5   2010-10-15 12:25:00
```

So the result of this should echo:

```
   for time_id 1: "Start 11:15  -  End 11:30"
   for time_id 2: "Start 11:35  -  End 11:55"
   for time_id 3: "Start 12:00  -  End 12:05"
   for time_id 4: "Start 12:10  -  End 12:10"
   for time_id 5: "Start 12:15  -  End 12:25"
```

Is this possible? Please help. I have been on this since morning. I tried using for loop but i keep getting weird errors.

Thanks Programming Guys!
:)

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Comment: Do you have a query already? Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: aah.. my eyes.. oh its not blinking ?!

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to stack overflow... I have removed it from the code... sorry guys

Comment: Oh noo... i have deleted it. But here is my new code: Connect to database $i = 0; while ($i <= $time_id +1) { if ($i != 0) { $Start_date = $start_time + 86400; } else { $end_time = $end_time - 86400; } $i++; I got it from the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    time_id, 
    MIN(time_duration) AS start_time, 
    MAX(time_duration) AS end_time
FROM 
    abc_table 
GROUP BY 
    time_id;
```

That should do the job.

Comment: WOW thanks for the speedy reply... Sorry for being retarded but how would i put the start_date into a variable... i.e. $start_date so that i can echo it in different locations...

Answer (score 1):

try with this. Maybe it can help you. You just need to change a little bit I guess:

```
 select concat_ws("","for time_id ","",time_id," ",min(time_duration)," - ",max(time_duration)) as result from table1 group by time_id;
```

it will give you this result:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| result                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| for time_id 1 2010-10-15 11:15:00 - 2010-10-15 11:30:00 |
| for time_id 2 2010-10-15 11:35:00 - 2010-10-15 11:55:00 |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT:** Just add what you need:

```
mysql> select concat_ws("","for time_id ","",time_id," ",min(TIME_FORMAT(time_duration,'%h:%i:%s'))," - ",max(TIME_FORMAT(time_duration,'%h:%i:%s'))) as result,
    -> DATE_FORMAT(time_duration,'%d-%m-%Y') as date
    -> from table1
    -> group by time_id;


+-----------------------------------+------------+
| result                            | date       |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
| for time_id 1 11:15:00 - 11:30:00 | 15-10-2010 |
| for time_id 2 11:35:00 - 11:55:00 | 15-10-2010 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: WOW thanks for the speedy reply... Sorry for being retarded but how would i put the start_date into a variable... i.e. $start_date so that i can echo it in different locations?

Comment: Woow Thank you soo much Trix!!!! One more thing. I have editted your code abit. Is this correct? :

Comment: Woow Thank you soo much Trix!!!! THATS AMAZING that you formatted the time as well. Just one more thing. How do I put the formatted time into a variable. Would it be like: `$start_date = min(TIME_FORMAT(time_duration,'%h:%i:%s'))` ?

Comment: I keep getting error messages Trix. This is what i have done.             `$dates = mysql_query("SELECT time_id, time_duration FROM               time_table' GROUP BY time_id");                                                                    while($raw = mysql_fetch_array($dates)){ 
 $time= $raw['time_duration']; $min_time = min(TIME_FORMAT(time_duration,'%h:%i:%s'))}`

Comment: No. Thats not what you suppose to do. I must admit I cant follow what you want to achieve? 
Either use select I gave you and then take data from it (you can add format data to sql string with basic concatenation ) 
or make your own select (or use Crozin's ) and with php change data that you want to echo (in that case look at php manual how to get right format for your datetime variable).